# Cocos2d & UIKit Popup

Tags: uikit, cocos2d-iphone, uialertview

i want to open some popup window like UIAlertView but with UITextField in my cocos2d game to ask a username for highscore list, is there any control for this? i had never work with UIKIt controls before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to me you can present a view controller when you want to submit the score.

In that view controller you can implement what ever you want implement..

```
UIViewController* myController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] presentModalViewController:myController animated:YES];
```

Try this if its creating some problem you can use :

```
UIViewController* myController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:myController.view];
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit tricky but ultimately straightforward once you write a few reusable classes for yourself.  To get started, try something like my answer here to this:

[Overlaying a UIView onto a Cocos layer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225511/overlaying-a-uiview-onto-a-cocos-layer/8240309#8240309)