# Xcode Views and Cocos2d Layers in one project

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, game-engine

I have task to make simple app from three Views:

- in first: UITableView (it needs to be first View when app starts)
- in second: UITextField
- in third: Cocos2d Layer

And maybe one more View for menu to switch between them. How can I mix ViewControllers and Layers in one project? Do i need start project from Xcode or Cocos2d template?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12900159/ccdirecter-replace-scene-with-uiview-nib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible approach is starting with a Cocos2D project and then using [CCUIViewWrapper](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/6889) to display any view as a `CCNode`. This approach is the best one if you can handle all of your views inside of the same Cocos2D scene.

If you are planning of building, e.g., a navigation controller based app, then the opposite strategy could be more adequate: start with a "normal" app and then, when you need it (i.e., in your third view controller), add Cocos2d's GLView to your view controller view:

```
[myViewController.view.layer addSublayer:[[CCDirector sharedDirector] glView].layer];
```

or:

```
[myViewController.view addSubview:[[CCDirector sharedDirector] glView]];
```

You will need to import QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h to be allowed to use CALayers.

Comment: In fact, The second approach would be more easy to use (just an opinion.)

Comment: i4Apple yes, in my case second way is more appropriate, because I need to have possibility to use navigation controller to switch between first and second Views

Comment: One more question: how I can import cocos2d files to project correctly? I added the libs folder and few frameworks what is cocos needed to work to the Xcode by dragging them into project. But it's many ARC warnings when i try to build

Comment: You should disable arc for all the Cocos2d files: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project